# PowerPoint VBA import image, then resize with constant aspect ratio

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to do what it says in the title. My Sub includes this:

```
Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPath & strTemp, _
                                  LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                                  SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                  Left:=35, _
                                  Top:=260, _
                                  Width:=-1, _
                                  Height:=245)

oPic.LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
oPic.Height = 255
```

But for some reason, the aspect ratio is not actually locked - the image height is being reduced to 255 points, but the width stays the same. Any ideas what I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
oPic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
```

Not, msoCTrue

I can recreate your problem using your code, and I can get the picture to behave by not specifying the height when I load the picture:

```
Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPath & strTemp, _
                                  LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
                                  SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
                                  Left:=35, _
                                  Top:=260, _
                                  Width:=-1, _
                                  Height:=-1)

oPic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
oPic.Height = 255
```

It looks like the aspect ratio is coming from the picture data -- not from your current scaling of the picture.  If this still doesn't achieve what you need, I can see 2 paths:

1. Update your picture file to meet the aspect ratio you really need, and then use the method above.
2. Programmatically set the aspect ratio you want by calculating height/width and setting them instead of using .lockaspectratio.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to change anything - aspect ratio still changes when reducing height of the image. Any other ideas?

Comment: @NilsGudat Updated the answer to include more.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, perfect, simply not specifying the height and modifying it after loading the picture works great! Don't really understand why, but I'll take it!